# error while deploying Google App Engine proxy server

Tags: google-app-engine

I am facing this error while deploying a proxy server on Google App Engine:

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Creating a composite index failed for entity_type: "EntryPoint"
ancestor: false
Property {
  name: "last_updated"
  direction: 2
}
: This index:
entity_type: "EntryPoint"
ancestor: false
Property {
  name: "last_updated"
  direction: 2
}

is not necessary, since single-property indices are built in. Please remove it from your index file and upgrade to the latest version of the SDK, if you haven't already.
--- end server output ---

Your app was updated, but there was an error updating your indexes. Please retry later with appcfg.py update_indexes.
2013-04-30 09:42:11 (Process exited with code 0)

You can close this window now.
```

Comment: @MoSha...were you able to figure this one?  I ran into the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to remove all or a part of that property for last_updated.  I'm still trying to figure out exactly what to remove msyelf, but will be sure to share as soon as I find out.

Thanks,
g